# URLSession for XMLParser in SwiftUI returning empty or nil

Tags: xml-parsing, swiftui

I am attempting to parse XML using an URLSession, XCode 12, SwiftUI but it keeps returning [] or nil.  If I print immediately after the parse(see code), all the data is there, but for some reason, it seems to be clearing it all out.

If I try it with a .xml file, the code works fine, so it must be something in my URLSession in a XMLParserDelegate class:

```
class ParseController: NSObject, XMLParserDelegate{
var items: [Item] = []
var itemStore: [Item]?

func loadData() {    
    let url = URL(string: "website")!    
    let request=URLRequest(url: url)
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
      if data == nil {
        print("dataTaskWithRequest error: \(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))")
        return
      }
      
      let parser = XMLParser(data: data!)
      parser.delegate=self
      parser.parse()
      
      self.itemStore=self.items
      print(self.itemStore)
    }
    task.resume()
    
    /*
    if let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Items", withExtension: "xml") {
        if let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: path) {
            parser.delegate = self
            parser.parse()
          self.itemStore=self.items
        }
    }
    */
  }
```

And then I call that with a button in my View:

```
struct MyParserView: View {
  @State var itemsResult: [Item]?
  
  var body: some View {
    if ((itemsResult?.isEmpty) == nil) {
      VStack {
        Text("Stuff here")
        Button(action: {
          let parserControl = ParseController()
          parserControl.loadData()
          itemsResult = parserControl.itemStore
        }){
          Text("Push")
        }
      }
    }else {
      List{
        ForEach(itemResult!, id:\.id){item in
          Text(item.name)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Convert the `data` to a string and make sure it’s the XML you expected. Also, in `XMLParserDelegate` implement the handler for errors, so it it failed, you can see what the error is.

Answer (score -1):

This was not a problem with XML, but lifecycle in SwiftUI.
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662429

TL;DR:  I published itemStore and now works great!

Comment: Any chance you could publish the working code? Cheers.